# Como limpar caracteres especiais da expressão document.getElementById("humidity").value;

Tags: javascript

Estou montando o meu *payload* mas ele está vindo assim:

```js
{
    "mode": "sync",
    "messageType": "57cd765743f3f9c473d5",
    "messages": [{
        "Humidity": "99.1",
        "Temperature": "99.2",
        "Brightness": "99.3",
        "Timestamp": "1999999999"
    }]
}
```

Quando deveria ir assim:

```js
{
    "mode": "sync",
    "messageType": "57cd765743f3f9c473d5",
    "messages": [{
        "Humidity": 25.7,
        "Temperature": 21.5,
        "Brightness": 13.0,
        "timestamp": 1413100000
    }]
}
```

Código:

```js
//Creates a new Messaging.Message Object and sends it to the HiveMQ MQTT Broker
var publish = function(payload, topic, qos) {

    mensagem.Humidity = document.getElementById("humidity").value;
    mensagem.Temperature = document.getElementById("temperature").value;
    mensagem.Brightness = document.getElementById("brightness").value;
    mensagem.Timestamp = document.getElementById("timestamp").value;

    pl.messages = new Array();
    pl.messages[0] = mensagem;

    console.log(JSON.stringify(pl));

    //Send your message (also possible to serialize it as JSON or protobuf or just use a string, no limitations)
    var message = new Messaging.Message(payload);
    message.destinationName = topic;
    message.qos = 2;

    //message.retained = true;
    client.send(message);
}
```

Como eu faço para limpar essas "" sobrando no meu *payload*?

Comment: Como assim? Você quer enviar um JSON inválido mesmo? Pq o primeiro valor é o correto, não tem "aspas sobrando". Já o segundo é inválido, se quiser testar: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Não entendi bem... porque mode" não pode conter a primeira " para ficar "mode"?

Comment: Nilson, obrigada pelo seu retorno...

O problema é um pouco maior que esse. Criei uma app bem simples, com 4 campos em tela e 4 botões. A ideia geral é colocar os dados na tela, me conectar com meu CLOUD MQTT , e o cloud mqtt vai salvar os dados inputados na tela em uma tabela do meu banco de dados SAP HANA... 

Testando via web, quando eu coloco o payload abaixo, os dados são gravados corretamente na tabela do meu banco SAP HANA: 
{mode":"sync","messageType":"57cd765743f3f9c473d5","messages":[{"Humidity":25.7, "Temperature": 21.5, "Brightness": 13.0, "timestamp":1413100000}]}

Comment: Nilson, obrigada pelo seu retorno...

O problema é um pouco maior que esse. Criei uma app bem simples, com 4 campos em tela e 4 botões. A ideia geral é colocar os dados na tela, me conectar com meu CLOUD MQTT , e o cloud mqtt vai salvar os dados inputados na tela em uma tabela do meu banco de dados SAP HANA... 

Testando via web: 

Colocando o payload 1 não grava nada na minha tabela, colocando o payload 2 (gerado pela minha app), grava os dados na minha tabela ...

Comment: Talvez porque você está enviando os números como string. `"foo": "32"` e `"foo": 32` são coisas diferentes. Duvido muito que tenha relação com as aspas.

Comment: hummm,mas como eu altero isso? Pode me dizer?

Answer (score 2):

O atributo `value` de um elemento HTML é sempre string.

Só o que tu precisa fazer é converter para `float` ou `int` de acordo com tua necessidade.

Exemplo:

```js
var input_int = document.getElementById('int').value;
var input_float = document.getElementById('float').value;
var input_string = document.getElementById('string').value;

// Todos são strings
console.log({
  "input_int": input_int,
  "input_float": input_float,
  "input_string": input_string
});

// Converte o que é número para o tipo correto
input_int = parseInt(input_int, 10);
input_float = parseFloat(input_float);

// Com os tipos corretos, o JSON é criado corretamente
console.log({
  "input_int": input_int,
  "input_float": input_float,
  "input_string": input_string
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="int" value="5" />
<br>
<input type="number" id="float" value="2.5" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="string" value="string" />
```

Comment: Obrigada pelo retorno Fernando :)

Answer (score 1):

Valores de campos HTML são strings. O JSON resultante de chamar `JSON.stringify` com esses valores realmente será um JSON cujos valores terão aspas duplas.

Se você não quer que o seu JSON contenha strings, você deve converter os seus valores para o tipo numérico do Javascript. No seu caso, o timeStamp é inteiro, então você pode usar a função [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) do Javascript:

```
mensagem.Timestamp = parseInt(document.getElementById("timestamp").value);
```

Já os demais valores não são inteiros. Para eles você usa a função [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

```
mensagem.Humidity = parseFloat(document.getElementById("humidity").value);
mensagem.Temperature = parseFloat(document.getElementById("temperature").value);
mensagem.Brightness = parseFloat(document.getElementById("brightness").value);
```

Comment: Pode usar um `Number(document.getElementById("brightness").value)` também :)

Comment: Renan! Funcionou! Agora consigo salvar os meus dados da tela na minha tabela do meu SAP HANA database (trial)!! Muito obrigada!!